# Find match count for given words with a given list using solr

Tags: solr, lucene, use-case

A car can have multiple features. A Customer needs multiple features. I would like to show how many features does a car match from the Customer's demand.

If Cars are:

> Honda: PowerSteering, AC, PowerWindow
>
> GM: PowerSteering, Sedan, CruiseControl

And

> Customer needs are: Sedan, CruiseControl.

Ques: How can I achieve the results as follows:

> Honda: 0 matching features out of 2.
>
> GM: 2 matching features out of 2.

I believe there would be some nice way of achieving this using apache solr.

EDIT: Edited to clarify the question.

Comment: I don't think I would use Solr for such a project.

Comment: You might have some chances with termfreq FunctionQuery in Solr4. But I can not confirm that as I'm using 3.5